# Can't use pip on one machine to install package that I successfully installed on another

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have been trying to install dependencies for a library on a colleagues Virtual Machine which is running XUbuntu 16.04. I have been able to install these dependencies on my own machine without a problem, however when attempting to install these dependencies using PIP on hers we get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package name> == <package version>
```

(where package name and package version are the corresponding details for the specific package that pip gets stuck on). The package it gets this error for is called catfish. I was able to install this package on my computer, although I can't find the package using pip3 when I search. I am using Python 3.5.2 but Python 2.7 is also installed on my virtual machine.

I have tried a few things to figure out why this is the case but have not been able to reach a result. I strongly suspect that if I understood how exactly pip works I would be able to solve this problem. If anyone has any tips on what I could do or where to look to get to the bottom of this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: pip3 install catfish

Comment: This is arguably better suited for askubuntu or superuser rather than SO...

Answer (score 1):

The `catfish` can be installed through `apt` , it is not avalaible through `pip`

To check the availability through `pip`  :

```
pip search package_name
```

To check the availability through `apt`:

```
sudo apt-cache policy package_name
```

e,g:

```
sudo apt-cache policy catfish
```

sample output:

```
catfish - File searching tool which is configurable via the command line
```